# G is a group and H is a subgroup of G. Find the index of...

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the index $[G:H]$ of $H=\langle3\rangle$; $G= \mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z}$

I am having difficulty understanding why the answer is 1.  I know that to find the index I can say that the order of $H$ is 7 since $H$ is the set $\{0,3,6,9,12,15,18\}$.  But how can I find the order of $\mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z}$ in order to find the index?

Comment: If $G=Z_{12}$ then $\left<3\right>$ has index $3$.

Comment: The fact that you got $|H| = 7$ should have risen alarm since $|G| = [G:H]|H|$ and $7$ doesn't divide $20$. Order of $G$ is $20$ since clearly there are $20$ elements in $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One finds $\left<3\right>=\{03,6,9,12,15,18,1,\ldots\}$
and as one has $1\in\left<3\right>$ then $\left<3\right>=G$.

Answer (score 1):

$H= \{ 0,3,6,9 \} $ as  you are in $\mathbb{Z} $ modulo $12$. Thus by lagrange's theorem  $ [G:H] = |G| / |H|  =12/ 4 = 3 $.

Comment: Whoops! I accidentally had Z mod 12 instead of Z mod 20. The answer in the back of my textbook says the index is 1. But I don't see how that is the case If I use this same process with Z mod 20

Comment: In the case of modulo $20$. you see $ 3 \times 7 =21 \equiv 1$ modulo $20$. So $1$ is there in $H$. Thus  $ 1\in H \implies  H= G$ and thus the index is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The group $H$ has to be intended as the subgroup $\langle [3]_{20}\rangle$. Since $\gcd(3,20)=1$ the element $[3]_{20}$ is a generator of $\Bbb Z_{20}$, hence $G=H$ and clearly $[G:H]=1$.